# Windows 7, SVN client authentication

Tags: svn, authentication, windows-7

Recently I installed new windows 7 in my system and then SVN client. Now when I gave my repository path and checked out the code then it directly checked out the code, without asking the password. I am sure I have configured my repository to ask for the password since I other users of that repository still requires to give their password. Kindly let me know if someone has face the same problem.

Best Regards, 
Aashutosh

Answer (score 1):

I think I got answer. Since I upgraded my system from windows XP to windows 7, but parent folder was still having .svn file in it and that's why when I check out the new folder code, it used the old authentication details form .svn and didn't asked for the password.

Best Regards,

Aashutosh

Comment: Subversion doesn't store your credentials in the .svn directories. The credentials are stored in %APPDATA%\Subversion and are (by default) encrypted with your Windows password.

Answer (score 0):

Is the repository username/password the same as your windows 7 account by any chance?

Comment: Does that matter? When I was using XP, then it was asking even then.

Comment: I have different username/password for windows 7 and repository. Kindly let me know if anyone knows the answer.